# enable TinyMCE for comment forms

Tags: tinymce, editor, visual-editor, comment-form

Is there any way in Wordpress to use a richt-text-editor (preferable the build in TinyMCE) on the comment form textarea in the frontend? I had such a feature in earlier versions, using the plugin "TinyMCEComment", but that one is not developed any further and is broken on 3.x versions. I've tried all related plugins on a Wordpress 3.4 installation, none of them is working (e.g. can't insert links, missing labels, …).

I also tried several ways of creating a plugin to enable the RTE for comments, like adding the the JS code manually. My last approach looked like:

```
function commentTinyMCE() {

    wp_editor( '', 'comment', array(
        'media_buttons' => false,
        'teeny' => true,
    ) );

}

/* hook into WordPress */
add_action('wp_footer', 'commentTinyMCE' );
```

As of what I could say after debugging is, that the function `wp_editor` does nothing.

Right now it seems to me, that is it impossible to integrate a useful, working RTE into the comment forms. Quicktags above the form is not what my customers are after.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: …should also be tagged as "rich-text-editor" or "RTE", but that tag doesn't exist on WP:SE and I haven't the right to create it.

Comment: @fischi "rich-tag-editor"? I meant a [rich-text editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_rich-text_editor).

Comment: ups, my mistake :D

Comment: check this tutoral: http://www.revood.com/blog/adding-visual-editor-to-wordpress-comments-box-part-2/

Comment: Please do not invent tags no one will subscribe to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the StackOverflow Editor for Comments, using the [WP Markdown](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-markdown/) Plugin.

If you want another one, try [TinyMCEComments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymcecomments/) or something like that. Didn't test this Plugin - but should work fine.

Comment: As I wrote in the question, the TinyMCEComments plugin doesn't work anymore with 3.x versions of WP. I'll need to ask my customer, if it's acceptable for him to see markup in the textarea – even if it's just simple Markdown. Nice hint, but waiting for more such answers.